# Command SHOW MASTER STATUS different in master and slave

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm using Bitnami MariaDB. I've done fixing the replication and now both `Slave_IO_Running` and `Slave_SQL_Running` has value `yes`. This is the whole output:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                   Master_Host: provisioner-peer
                   Master_User: repl
                   Master_Port: 3306
                 Connect_Retry: 10
               Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000025
           Read_Master_Log_Pos: 16161372
                Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.000014
                 Relay_Log_Pos: 156283
         Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000025
              Slave_IO_Running: Yes
             Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
               Replicate_Do_DB: 
           Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
            Replicate_Do_Table: 
        Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
       Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
   Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                    Last_Errno: 0
                    Last_Error: 
                  Skip_Counter: 7356
           Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 16161372
               Relay_Log_Space: 187679
               Until_Condition: None
                Until_Log_File: 
                 Until_Log_Pos: 0
            Master_SSL_Allowed: No
            Master_SSL_CA_File: 
            Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
               Master_SSL_Cert: 
             Master_SSL_Cipher: 
                Master_SSL_Key: 
         Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
 Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                 Last_IO_Errno: 0
                 Last_IO_Error: 
                Last_SQL_Errno: 0
                Last_SQL_Error: 
   Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
              Master_Server_Id: 89
                Master_SSL_Crl: 
            Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
                    Using_Gtid: No
                   Gtid_IO_Pos: 
       Replicate_Do_Domain_Ids: 
   Replicate_Ignore_Domain_Ids: 
                 Parallel_Mode: optimistic
                     SQL_Delay: 0
           SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
       Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
              Slave_DDL_Groups: 2
Slave_Non_Transactional_Groups: 0
    Slave_Transactional_Groups: 12
```

But when I run command `SHOW MASTER STATUS` on both master and slave, it has different output.

on master:

```
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| mysql-bin.000025 | 16817070 |              |                  |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
```

on slave:

```
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| mysql-bin.000004 |      390 |              |                  |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
```

I search for this but ended found nothing. Is it okay? or there is something I need to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem.

A server can be a Primary or a Replica or both or neither.  Your Replica seems to be both a "Master" (as indicated by `SHOW MASTER STATUS`) and a "Replica" (as indicated by `SHOW SLAVE STATUS`).

Your Replica is building a binlog file that may (or may not) be used by

- A backup mechanism being run on the Replica, and/or
- A downstream Replica which sees your current Replica at its "Master".

The binlogs, and the positions in them, are not likely to be the same.

Comment: Ah, I see. It's pretty clear now for me. Thank you for your great answer!

Answer (score 0):

There is a strong likelihood you forgot to configure [log-slave-updates](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_slave_updates) on the slave. If you are using MySQL 8.0.26 and above, it would be [log_replica_updates](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_replica_updates).

Please add this line to your my.cnf if you are using MySQL 8.0.26 and above

```
[mysqld]
log_replica_updates
```

Please add this line to your my.cnf if you are using MySQL 8.0.25 and prior

```
[mysqld]
log_slave_updates
```

Then, restart mysqld on the Slave and the binary logs on the Slave will start increasing.

The binary logs events from the Master were executed on the Slave but were  not recorded on the Slave's local binary logs. The data should be fine.

NOTE : [log-slave-updates](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_slave_updates) is deprecated but still works for now. Once you upgrade past MySQL 8.0.25, please start using [log_replica_updates](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_replica_updates).

Comment: I just noticed you are using MariaDB. Just use `log_slave_updates`

Comment: Thank you for your great recommendation!